# Сортировка for [Twig]

Tags: php, twig, sympy

Есть массив, вывожу в шаблон:

```
$languages = array(
    'us' => 'English',
    'tr' => 'Türkçe',
    'ru' => 'Русский',
);

$twig->addGlobal('languages', $languages);
```

Вывожу в шаблон Twig с помощью **for** все строки. Делаю **if** значение, чтобы выделить нужный язык, но он стоит последним по списку, так же как и в массиве. Как сделать его первым по списку? Код:

```
{% for key, lang in languages %}
  {% if key == 'ru' %}
    {{ lang }}
  {% else %}
    {{ lang }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/sort.html

Answer (score 1):

Решил данный вопрос таким образом:
Создал 2 **for**, в одном поставил условие проверки на соответствие, в другом обратное:

```
{% for key, lang in languages %}
   {% if key == 'ru' %}
     {{ lang }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for key, lang in languages %}
  {% if key != 'ru' %}
    {{ lang }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: А `{{ languages['ru'] }}` не проще сначала вывести?